# osx system audio through a plugin?

Tags: effects, osx, vst

i was wondering if anybody knows an osx tool/software that would let you run system audio (all sources) through a vst plugin? 
 say you want apply a compressor to whatever you are listening to? thank you!

Answer (score 3):

could you maybe use Soundflower to route the system audio into a vst compatible program? just an idea.

Comment: Why is this voted down? This absolutely works, I regularly use it to route standalone sound utilities (like WaveWarper) into Pro Tools. This utility creates an i/o for your system audio and you just route the Soundflower/system output into your DAW of choice and apply whatever effects you'd like.

Comment: Maybe, but this isn't actually an answer, it's itself a question. Installing soundflower is trivial: then what? There's no preferences icon for controlling it, no GUI, no terminal commands, just "use soundflower" doesn't in anyway help getting audio to go through a VST before coming out your speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Audio Hijack Pro is another option.
http://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/

Answer (score 0):

Wiretap Studio should let you do that
http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/wiretap/

Answer (score 0):

Or [Jack](http://jackaudio.org/), but you will need to use a plugin host of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

[Blue Cat Audio's Patchwork](http://www.bluecataudio.com/Products/Product_PatchWork/) has a standalone version that allows you to stack any flavor of plugins between any input and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

[menuBus](https://menubus.audio) and [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) are two products worthwhile mentioning. menuBus gives the option to put your combined system audio output (from all applications) through a stack of AU plugins. Loopback creates virtual audio devices that allow e.g. to route Spotify/iTunes/Skype/etc. from or to other apps.

Answer (score -2):

Soundflower is the most versatile of all the options proposed